# Disable aero fade-in effect on dialog

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog, aero

I have a modal dialog I'm creating with MFC.  When it appears, the Aero theme does it's fade-in transition for a new window appearing.  In my particular case I'm switching immediately from one dialog to another and the fade effect is distracting.  Is there a way it can be disabled so the window immediately appears, like it does when Aero is disabled, but without switching Aero off completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DwmSetWindowAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969524%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function might be able to help you. It lets you modify a number of window attributes related to the DWM. In particular, the `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED` attribute mentions "Enable or forcibly disable DWM transitions", which just might do the trick.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
LPCVOID dwAttribute  = (LPCVOID)TRUE;

hr = DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, 
        &dwAttribute, sizeof(dwAttribute));

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
   // The transitions should have been disabled
}
```

Comment: Just be sure to use some form of soft linking, whether delay loading or explicit `GetProcAddress`, because DWM functions won't exist on pre-Vista windows.