# Deal with unloading forms on Windows 7 Aero theme

Tags: windows-7, vb6, aero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable aero fade-in effect on dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897070/disable-aero-fade-in-effect-on-dialog)

I am trying to take a screen shot of the application when a user presses okay on a form. When the user presses OK, the form should unload, then take a screen shot of the MDI form.

However, with the Windows 7 Aero theme, the form doesn't disappear right away, it fades out. So the code to take the screen shot occurs before the form is completely vanished.

Is there any way to get the code to halt until the form is 100% gone. I have thought about sleep, but was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Related question: [Disable aero fade-in effect on dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897070/disable-aero-fade-in-effect-on-dialog)

Answer (score 2):

You can call `DwmSetWindowAttribute()` with the `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED` attribute. This should then allow it to disappear immediately.

In my situation, I was taking a screenshot after showing a message box so I had to fall back to a 200ms `Sleep()`.

Comment: Recently on The Old New Thing -- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/03/10355307.aspx

Comment: @wqw Ah-ha, that's where I saw it! Thanks :)